# Undoing a button Click

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a button (named randomGenerator) that everytime you press it, it generates random statements. How can I create a button (undoButton) that when clicked will undo the action that randomGenerator called and take you back to the statement before it? So basically I want to undo a button action method based of a button click:

```
-(void) randomGeneratorClicked {

      //generate a random statement

}

-(void) undoButtonClicked {

    //undo the action that [self randomGeneratorClicked] has done
}
```

Comment: You should add the code for the 'randomGeneratorClicked`. Without knowing that it is unclear what needs to be "undone".  What is undo supposed to do ?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should read about [`NSUndoManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/index.html).

When you generate a new random value, you can use the `registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object:` method to store the previous value.

When the user taps the undo button, you can call the `undo` method on the undo manager to step backwards through the undo history.